# Why is memory in neural turing machine, differential neural computer and the like called 'external'?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

Neural turing machines and differential neural computers are wholly differentiable, so why is their memory called "external"? External in relation to what, why isn't for example LSTM cell state isn't external and NTM's memory is?